# Count down to EST Hour everyday?

Tags: php, time, countdown, mktime

How would i count down to a specific hour every day, say 12PM EST time... So that it would countdown as 1 Hour 56 Minutes until 12PM / Lunch? I'm looking for something short and simple, no need for CSS or JS as it will be text and only update when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i was looking for in case it will help someone else.

```
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute)
{

$the_countdown_date = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
$current = time();

$difference = $the_countdown_date - $current;
if ($difference < 0) $difference = 0;

$days = floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours = floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes = floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);

echo "Checkback in ".$hours." hours and ".$minutes." minutes";
}

countdown(2016,1,1,12,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have heard, but there's this trillion dollar site called [google.com](http://www.google.com). You can search terms that will give you the **best** results on the web! Try it sometime, hella useful.

Check it out, here's the first result from it!

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/04/9-cool-jquery-countdown-scripts.html

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to do it in PHP no JS and ive messed around and researched already, im simply not coming up with the right solution... otherwise i wouldnt post a question. Thanks for the flame and link to google.